# Facebook Comments Box - access all the comments on my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

How can I access all the comments from the Facebook Comments Box on my website?

When I checked the Facebook documentation, I have this link:

The comments for every URL can be accessed via the graph API. Simply go to: https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids={YOUR_URL}.

But it's only for one page, I want the global result for all the pages in the website.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can add yourself as a moderator (which is probably a good idea anyways) by adding this in head:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="{YOUR_FACEBOOK_USER_ID}"/>
```

Or you can instead add a Facebook application (and all the moderators of that app) with:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{YOUR_APPLICATION_ID}"/>
```

(but note that you can't do both).

Having done that, you can see all the comments to moderate here:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments?view=queue

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be anyway to subscribe to this queue.